# Asus Xonar Essence II STX, Equalizer is not available

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus

Like the topic saying I just switched to Ubuntu and I want to use the Equalizer from my ASUS card instead of using Equalizer software which I tried the PulseEffects and Pulse Audio Equalizer and sound is not accurate as the built-in equalizer from ASUS drivers on Windows. This is very disappointing for me to not use the Equalizer incorporated from my sound card to Linux OS.

Comment: Hi @ginko, do you have a question? Your post sounds more like a complaint than a question. Are you looking for Asus drivers for your sound card? It would help if you posted details about the hardware if you'd like people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A review of your sound card support files shows [Asus does not include](https://www.asus.com/Sound-Cards/Essence_STX_II_71/HelpDesk_Download/) an Equalizer for any version of Linux; only for Windows are there drivers.

This is a common issue, and I'm carefully shopping before buying my next upgrade components to make sure what I buy includes Ubuntu compatible drivers, for manufacturers often just make Windows drivers because Windows dominates the desktop market.

Answer (score 0):

This card does not have an equalizer.

The Windows driver comes with a software equalizer. In Linux, you have to use any other software equalizer.